# For-each loop & IF statement: checking running process ID numbers

Tags: powershell, if-statement, foreach

I need help writing a for-each loop to iterate through all of the processes running on my system. Within the for-each loop, I need to write an IF statement to check if the ID number is greater than 10000. If the ID is greater than 10000, it must display the message “[Process Name] has an ID greater than 10000.” Else, no message needs to be displayed.

I'm a complete newbie to Powershell and I truly cannot figure this one out.
Any assistance would be of great help.
Here is what I have so far:

```
$theprocessID = Get-Process | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Id -gt 10000}


foreach ($theprocess in $relatedprocess)
{
    if ($theprocess -gt 10000)
    {$_.computername 
    write-output "has an ID greater than 10000."}
}
```

Comment: .. .sounds like homework. If it is  you should talk about this with your teacher. BTW: You limit the list of processes saved to your variable `$theprocessID` to processes with IDs greater than (-gt) 15000.  ;-)

Comment: @olaf Filters out those below 15000, checks for those over 10000 (which would be all according to the first filter), then says they are over 1000. I’m confused!

Comment: No. Your `Where-Object` filters out all process IDs less than or eqal to 15,000. In your loop you check for IDs greater than or equal to 10,000. At least that's the code you posted.

Comment: HAHA It is homework! But my professor doesn't read his E-Mails plus I have trouble understanding his explanations.

Comment: If you use `Where-Object {$_.ID -gt 10000}`you don't need an if statement to check if the ID is greater than 10000.

Comment: What Olaf said is true, that will only return those with an ID greater than 10000

Comment: Try `Get-Process | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Id -gt 10000} | Select-Object -Property Id, ProcessName`